# Входит ли data labeling в обязанности техника-программиста?

Tags: веб-программирование, нейронные-сети, разметка

У меня такой вопрос. Я техник-программист и мне хотят поручить data labeling или по-другому обязанности по дейта-разметке. Работа заключается в том, чтобы учить нейросеть распознавать определенные объекты на изображениях и для этого я должна отмечать в начале сама объекты на картинках, которые бы я хотела, чтобы нейросеть выделяла. Работа очень муторная. Мне бы не хотелось заниматься ей и это не способствует развитию моих профессиональных качеств как программиста. Да и менеджер очень грубая на этом проекте и мне бы не хотелось с ней работать, а она заставляет. Вопрос, скажите, пожалуйста, имеет ли право организация мне сделать выговор, если я откажусь? Мне кажется, что это не входит в круг моих обязанностей, но я не уверенна из-за малого опыта в этой сфере.

Comment: мне трудно себе представить должностную инструкцию, в которой был бы пассаж о необходимости выполнения "муторной работы") Поставьте себя на место менеджера - 1) работа должна быть выполнена 2) давать эту работу Data Scientist'ам - дорогое удовольствие. Соответственно если бы я был на месте менеджера - то я бы постарался найти максимально доступную по цене рабочую силу для решения этой задачи - например нанял бы студентов-практикантов.

Comment: Попробуйте поговорить с менеджером и объяснить ему, что при выполнении монотонной работы, вы быстро устаете и начинаете делать много ошибок и вообще очень медленно работать :-D

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте свой договор о работе, если он есть. Если работа, которую вас заставляют делать, подходит под один из пунктов обязанностей,  то вы обязаны делать эту работу.

Data-labeling, который вы описали, подходит под "обучение нейросетей", чем вполне могут заниматься программисты.

Грубый менеджер - эта проблема не касается темы разработки.

Comment: Должностная инструкция что-то типа этого  
 http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_58804/733088bef66ec6952020b6bb012cd09c544c95b9/.

Меня смущает пункт "Участвует в выполнении различных операций технологического процесса обработки информации (прием и контроль входной информации, подготовка исходных данных, обработка информации, выпуск исходящей документации и передача ее заказчику). " Это он автоматизированно подготавливает данные или это имеется в виду какая-то ручная загрузка в базу данных? Другими словами, загрузка данных вручную в базу данных - это работа программиста?

Comment: Програмист может выполнять и такую работу. Не думайте что работа программиста - это сплошь интересные задачи

Comment: Я когда-то тоже в шоке был, когда половину своего программистского рабочего времени тратил на ручную резку pdf файлов и подготовку форм excel для заполнения пользователями. Хорошо, что я из той конторы давно уволился.