# Разметка данных (data labeling)

Tags: веб-программирование, нейронные-сети

У меня такой вопрос. Я техник-программист и мне поручили разметку данных (data labeling). Но я не хочу ее делать, потому что это муторный процесс. Начальство говорит, что согласно должностной инструкции я должна ее делать. И они мне привели пункт:
что в рамках трудовой функции формализация и алгоритмизация поставленных задач я должна выполнять любые работы. В том числе почему-то написание модульных и интеграционных тестов. Это правда? Формализация - это что-то описание задачи? Это что реально под это требование можно что хочешь заставить, хоть аналитика, хоть тестирование?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Входит ли data labeling в обязанности техника-программиста?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1238648/%d0%92%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-data-labeling-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: если у вас нет отдела тестеров, то кто-то же должен писать тесты?? Чем по-вашему вообще должен заниматься "техник-программист"??

Comment: тот мой вопрос закрыли, потому что я не привела должностную инструкцию. Здесь уже выдержка из должностной инструкции.

Comment: Если начальство хочет забивать гвозди микроскопом, то трудовой кодекс тут бессилен.

Answer (score 2):

Особенно мне нравятся теги: "веб-программирование, нейронные-сети". Вам бы на форму к юристам, а не программистам. Там бы вам разъяснили, что вы должны делать, а что нет.

Поручить размечать могут по разным причинам, как-то:

- кто-то должен, почему не вы? Вы считаете эту работу недостойной вас? Или не соответствующей вашей квалификации?
- поручили, потому-что для другой работы, которую надо выполнять у вас недостаточно квалификации, а увольнять вас по сокращению не хочется - вот и нагрузили работой, что-бы как то обосновать выплату вам зарплаты.
- поручили, потому что вы самая ответственная и скрупулёзная в вашей конторе и никто другой с этой работой не справится.

Так-же напонятно, чем вам не нравиться "написание модульных и интеграционных тестов." Это действительно непростая работа. Боитесь, что не справитесь?

А что до "формализации" - то лично я бы никогда этого не поручил технику-программисту. Потому как на мой взгляд формализация задачи - один из самых важных этапов проектирования ИС, от качества которого зависит очень много чего. Но вашему начальству виднее -  может ваша квалификация  и многолетний опыт это вам и позволит, мы же не знаем.

А чисто по-человечески. Не хотите что-то делать - увольняйтесь. Вы же не в рабстве.
Ну даже предположим, вы будете судиться и выиграете суд у своей конторы. Дальше-то что?

Comment: я не говорю о том, что мне не надо поручать. Я сказала о том, что мне бы не хотелось ее делать, потому что с этой работой моя квалификация не повысится. И вопрос не об этом, а просто подходит пункт формализация и алгоритмизация в разметку? Какая связь между разметкой и формализацией и алгоритмизацией? И тесты пишутся на последнем этапе разработки, я ничего не имею против них, мне не понятно, почему они тоже идут в рамках формализации и алгоритмизации. Я просто боюсь, что мне так и будут всегда давать черновую работу. И причем все было в жесткой форме. Так я конечно думаю об увольнении.